# Display content of html email template as text instead of hyperlink

Tags: email, email-template, email-alert

I have one HTML email template with letterhead when I send it to the users some of the text like email addresses or text similar to the domain name (e.g. salesforce.com) is turning into a hyperlink.

I don't want them to show up as hyperlink instead I want them as plain text.

Comment: Is this happening in the actual email sent, or is it the email client inferring that these are to be links?

Comment: it's happening in the actual email send